# Failed to open Onyx

Tags: macos

Since one of OSX Lion's software update I'm facing a strange behavior with some of the apps installed on my mac.

For example with Onyx - when launching it by double click on Onyx.app I'm getting the following error:

`AppleScript Error:

sh: sw_vers: command not found (127).`

If I run Open Onyx.app, it works OK.

I've been trying to re-install OSX from Mac OSX utilities, and it was OK but after the first OSX software upgrade that error occurs.

I'm not sure is the default path setting issues since cat /etc/paths yields the following:

/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin

What is wrong with my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin to the PATH variable in

/private/etc/launchd.conf solved the issue.